Python Seaborn bar graph from DataFrame of wide measurements
I'm struggling with issue of creating a bar graph showing occurrences of measurements stored in DataFrame.
DataFrame has 3 columns (measurement devices name). In each column there are stored measurements values (they are not related to each other)
myExampleDataFrame
I'm looking the way to show occurrences of each measurement value on graph where bars will be columns (measurement devices name).
Till now I'm able to display occurrences in console (separately for each column)
# initialize list of lists
data2 = [[0.5, 0.5, 0.75], [1, 0.75, 0.75], [0.5, 0.75, 0.75], [0.75, 1, 0.75], [0.75, 1, 0.5] , [0.5, 1.5, 0.5]]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['Aw1', 'Aw2', 'Bw1'])

for ind in df2:
    print(df2[ind].value_counts())

Aw1
0.50    3
0.75    2
1.00    1
Name: count, dtype: int64
Aw2
0.75    2
1.00    2
0.50    1
1.50    1
Name: count, dtype: int64
Bw1
0.75    4
0.50    2
Name: count, dtype: int64

I'm also able to draw a chart but only presenting single column
sns.catplot(x=df2['Aw1']
        data=df2, 
        aspect=2, 
        kind='count')

Im looking for graph to display all columns at one graph.
So x line to be : 0.50   0.75  1.00  1.50
and on y  to be shown occurences from each column (for every x will be 3 bars)
something like this
BarGraphManyCategories

Code
import seaborn as sns
tmp = df2.stack().reset_index()
sns.barplot(tmp, x="level_0", y=0, hue='level_1')


If you want to modify the x-label and y-label, there are several ways to do so, but the simplest is to rename the columns in the variable tmp.

thanks  Idea with creation of temp df = df2.stack().reset_index()  was the hint I need.  The graph is not exactly the one I need but I was able to solve it by using catplot and options you proposed.   I edited original question with solution using your hint

I finally find solution using hints by Panda Kim:
tmp = df2.stack()  # create tem df with stack all columns in two
tmp = tmp.reset_index() # after stack it puts new indexes to df
print(tmp)      # see how it looks now

sns.set_style('whitegrid')
gr = sns.catplot(x=0, #column with measurements values in new tmp df
            data=tmp, 
            aspect=2,
            hue='level_1', 
            kind='count')  # ten typ wykresu sam zlicza ilosc wystapien w df

for ax in gr.axes.flat:  # ten kod dodaje opisy na szczycie wykresu (ilosc wystapien) 
    for c in range (0 , len(ax.containers)):
        ax.bar_label(ax.containers[c], size = 12, color = '#2d3047')


